# Espacio vacío al costado de la página

Tags: html, css, responsive

[image: Todo en la página es completamente responsive, pero queda todo ese bulto al costado de la página y no tengo ni la menor idea de como quitarlo, previamente habilité la función de overflow-x:hidden para que no se deslice horizontalmente hacia la derecha, funcionó pero en cuanto lo subí y lo probé desde mi celular no funcionaba, la página podía deslizarse horizontalmente hacia la derecha, a lo cual, estuve tratando de quitar ese espacio vacío del costado para no tener que deshabilitar el desplazamiento horizontal (ya que no funciona para dispositivos móviles). Les dejo adjuntado tanto el código css como el html, no coloqué la parte del responsive (max-width, etc) ya que el código completo cuenta con casi 2.000 líneas, por favor ignoren la redundancia e infeciencia en todo el código, empecé hace 3 semanas a aprender y aún me falta mucho por comprender, les agradeceré eternamente su ayuda! Estaré atento, saludos y gracias de antemano!]

Todo en la página es completamente responsive, pero queda todo ese bulto al costado de la página y no tengo ni la menor idea de como quitarlo, previamente habilité la función de `overflow-x:hidden` para que no se deslice horizontalmente hacia la derecha, funcionó pero en cuanto lo subí y lo probé desde mi celular no funcionaba, la página podía deslizarse horizontalmente hacia la derecha, a lo cual, estuve tratando de quitar ese espacio vacío del costado para no tener que deshabilitar el desplazamiento horizontal (ya que no funciona para dispositivos móviles). Les dejo adjuntado tanto el código css como el html, no coloqué la parte del responsive (max-width, etc) ya que el código completo cuenta con casi 2.000 líneas, por favor ignoren la redundancia e infeciencia en todo el código, empecé hace 3 semanas a aprender y aún me falta mucho por comprender, les agradeceré eternamente su ayuda! Estaré atento, saludos y gracias de antemano!

[Aquí les dejo el enlace de Github, el html está bajo el nombre de "index" y el css está bajo el nombre de "EstiloNuevo"](https://github.com/mate1891927/Nueva-pagina)

Comment: El código para poder replicar tu escenario y tener un [mcve] va en tu pregunta por favor

Answer (score 1):

El gran espacio vacío de la derecha es provocado por el `width` de tu `.header1`, intenta eliminar esa propiedad del css y dejar la que ya usas en el `header`. En caso de que requieras ese `width` en algún 'breakpoint', podrías utilizarlo dentro de un `media-query`.

[image: Ejemplo1]

Sin embargo, cuando quitas esa propiedad, aún queda un pequeño espacio. Este se debe al `margin: -20px;` que tienes en tu clase `.contenedor2`.

[image: Ejemplo2]

De esta forma, ya no tendrás la barra horizontal de desplazamiento, sin embargo, el banner y el pie de página que tienes se verán diferente a como lo tenías originalmente, para arreglar esto, podrías quitar el `padding` que tienes en la clase `.main` de tu `.contenedor2`

[image: Ejemplo3]

Y finalmente, agregar el `padding` al pie de página, para este caso, lo ideal sería crear un estilo para la clase `.texto200` y ajustarlo según prefieras.

[image: Ejemplo4]

Cabe recalcar, que al realizar esto, la página se veía bien en la resolución de mi pantalla y sin el código que mencionaste que no agregaste en los archivos, puedes intentar los pasos que te mencioné y nos cuentas como se vería en tu móvil.